# Windows 10 Autologin after hibernate

Tags: windows-10, automation, hibernate, standby, auto-login

On a PC running WIndows 10 Professional 1809, I have a local user configured for autologin, i.e. after a system reboot, this user is logged in automatically, without having to enter the password.

However, when I am logged in with that user, and send the system to sleep or hibernate, Windows requires me to enter the password for that user before I can login.

I would like to make Windows login that user in any situation, i.e. not only after reboot, but also after standby or hibernate, without any further manual interaction like pushing a login button on the welcome-screen (this is what happens when you use a user without a password) or having to answer a password.

Which settings are required for this scenario to work?

Comment: Check if disabling require sign-on after wake fixes it. https://www.top-password.com/blog/stop-windows-10-from-asking-for-password-after-sleep/

Comment: worked for me!
@Appleoddity thanks for your response