# Prevent landscape image + sign in when resuming from sleep with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sleep

When resuming from sleep on Windows 10 22H2, I have :

- a random landscape photo with some information
- if I click, I get a "sign in" button (I don't use any password anyway)

How to prevent this to happen, i.e. **how to go back to desktop when resuming from sleep?**

NB:

- I have already tried the methods from [here](https://www.top-password.com/blog/stop-windows-10-from-asking-for-password-after-sleep/):

  - method 1 : fail : I don't have this option, [as shown here](https://www.top-password.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/stop-require-password-from-sleep.png)
  - method 2 : fail : I already tried `gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management > Sleep Settings > Require a Password when the computer wakes > Disabled`, but after a reboot, a sleep, and a restore from sleep, the landscape photo comes again.
- this doesn't help: [Windows 10 Autologin after hibernate](https://superuser.com/questions/1398196/windows-10-autologin-after-hibernate)

Comment: go into settings, type in Screen saver in a search box and click on the option "Turn Screen Saver on or off". It will open old-style window (Win7 style), where you should have the option to uncheck "On resume, display logon screen". Note: you may have that greyed out depending on Windows version and GPO settings. Technically, you changed that with Method 2, but it's always better do stuff like this in Windows using GUI, not regedit.

Answer (score 1):

I originally did

*gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management > Sleep Settings > Require a Password when the computer wakes (Plugged-in) > Disabled*

and I forgot to do:

*Require a Password when the computer wakes (Battery) > Disabled*

This solves it!